# Can I disable a drop down list without using disable in javascript?

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net-mvc

I have a drop down list that gets enabled/disabled based on a checkbox onclick. On my debugging my object reference is not set when my checkbox is disabled in my controller.

CONTROLLER

```
Subject = Request.Form["DetailSelect" + rowID].ToString();
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
ddlSelect.disabled = !ddlSelect.disabled;
```

ASPX

```
<select = id="detailSelect<%=item.rowID"%> name="DetailSelect<%=item.rowID%>">
     <option value="">--Choose One--</option>
     <option value="Math">Math</option>
     <option value="English">English</option>
     <option value="History">History</option>
</select>
```

Where do I go to disable my drop down list, without using the disabled toggle in javascript?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did a little workaround where I used a hidden object and before I disable my drop down in the javascript function, I assign the value to my hidden input.

ASPX

```
<input id="hiddenSelect" type="hidden" name="HiddenSelect" value="" />
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
var ddlSelect = document.getElementById('detailSelect' + rowID).value;
document.getElementById('hiddenSelect').value = ddlSelect;
ddlSelect.disable = !ddlSelect.disabled;
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't use the disabled property, you can do it with an attribute:

```
<select ... disabled="disabled"></select>
```

Comment: Is this accessable in the controller with my Request.Form code?

Answer (score 1):

You can do that via jquery

```
 $("input[id$='chkbox']").click(function() {  
            $("select[id$='ddl']").attr("disabled", !$(this).is(":checked"));  
       }); });
```

where chkbox is the Id of the checkbox and ddl is the ID of the drop down list

Comment: Is this accessable in the controller with my Request.Form code?

Comment: There is a nice article which tells us why disabled controls are not posted to the web server and explores some of the workarounds to this problem.

http://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/012506-1.aspx
under the heading "Fixing the Disabled Form Fields Problem By Using a "Faux" Disabled State"